# Underlined Fieldset Legend

Tags: html, css, border, legend, fieldset

I am working on a small interface, and currently have a simple set of radio buttons inside a fieldset with a legend. It currently looks like this:

[image: what it is now]

But I want to get a border between the legend and the buttons, like so:

[image: what I want it to be]

The code is as follows:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Size:</legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" checked="checked" /> Small
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium" /> Medium
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="big" /> Big
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `fieldset{
 border:none;
 border-top: 1px solid;
 
}` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that before - all it does is leave the top side of the border in the first image in!

Comment: The closest I could get is `fieldset{
 border:none;
 
}
legend{
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
    margin: inherit;
}` which leaves the length of the line equal to the length of the text in the legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fieldset { 
  border: none;
}
legend {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/4fmnrs2w/)

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!